# How to use goto statement in lambda expression C++

Tags: c++

Is there any way to use goto statement in lambda expression?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto lambda = []() {
        goto label;
        return;
    };
    lambda();
    return 0;
label:
    std::cout << "hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

I want the console to output hello, world!, but the compiler gives an error:

```
use of undeclared label 'label'
        goto label;
             ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: This code is fairly confusing, you should really avoid using `goto` like that, the odds of nothing going wrong are fairly slim. If you could share what you actually wanted to achieve, we might be able to help with that.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve with goto inside a lambda?

Comment: @Qubit Maybe my example does not convey very well, but whether or not to use goto statement  is not the key of this question.

Comment: @0x11901 My point was related more to the fact of even considering `goto` to move between functions, think of all the issues that arise from something like this, it would become fairly difficult to keep track of what the code does. Not to mention, you then have a function that never reaches the `return` statement, which seems to defeat the purpose. So the point was, there should never even be a case where you would want to do this, regardless of whether or not it is possible.

Comment: @Qubit I want to implement complex loop iterations through for-like functions, accepting its body as a lambda. Now, it would be convenient to have a break-loop functionality like `break`, but the only way to achieve that would be through a lambda-breaking `goto`. So - there you have it - an example where it could be useful. A possible walkaround that I can see, is a continuation passing style, where the body accepts `continue` and `break` as functions to continue. Possible, but very not-C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use `goto` to move between functions, and a lambda defines a separate function to it's enclosing scope.

From [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto)

> The `goto` statement must be in the same function as the label it is referring, it may appear before or after the label.

And [the standard, `[stmt.goto]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.goto#1)

> The `goto` statement unconditionally transfers control to the statement labeled by the identifier. The identifier shall be a label located in the current function.

Answer (score 16):

> Is there any way to use goto statement in lambda expression?

No. Not to leave the scope of lambda and jump to the enclosing scope. You can only `goto` a labeled statement inside the lambda, same as if it were any other function.

Having said that, the uses for `goto` in C++ specifically are few and infrequent. There are other, *better*, options. I urge you not to reach for `goto` as the first tool you use.

Comment: Actually I can't come up with a single use case of `goto` in C++. In C, I still use it for error handling from time to time.

Comment: @liliscent - I can't come up with one either (unless I'm in some sort of overly constraint environment). But I don't want to make an argument out of ignorance by saying there absolutely is no use.

Comment: Some state machines are more clearly coded (and more efficient) using goto instead of other techniques.  Some C-based SDKs (even when used with C++... say Carbon for example) use goto as the paradigm for error handling.

Comment: @liliscent Isn't there one for breaking out of multiple loops?  I can't think of a better one if you want to break out of all of them at once (even though most of the time it makes more sense to return, I can see a use there).

Comment: @Spitemaster you use `return` to break out of a deep loop

Comment: @Caleth Yes, usually.  But there are times where `goto` makes the code look cleaner.  It's not common, but the situations exist.  I can contrive a scenario if you'd like, but that's not the point.

Comment: @Caleth You use `goto` when you can just leave the function containing multiple loops. But if you just want to break a few loops up, then `goto` is the only option.

Comment: @CygnusX1 you can also move the inner loops in their own function. `[&]{` ... `}()` can turn `goto` into `return`

Comment: @Caleth I stand corrected. Somehow I didn't think of that... I can think of cases when it won't work (e.g. multiple breaks to different loop level nesting), but usually it will suffice, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The [`goto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) statement transfers control to the location specified by label. The `goto` statement must be in the same function as the label it is referring, it may appear before or after the label.

You can instead do this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto lambda = []() {
        goto label;        
        return;
label:
        std::cout << "hello, world!" << std::endl;        
    };
    lambda();
    return 0;

}
```

And it will print "Hello World". See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c37ddd1e250fa6e9).